# Are there any common (preferably somewhat complex) organic molecules that help combat ocean pollution?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm participating in an activity where I need to present a topic/molecule in organic chemistry, and I am pretty passionate about "reversing"/helping with cleaning the ocean. I was wondering if there are any organic molecules that help with this or with lessening the effects of pollution. If you could let me know what solutions they are used in that would be a great help also. Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably not in the sense that you might mean. What do you mean by "combat pollution"? Perhaps you can be more specific, for instance, do you mean point source pollution, such as water draining from a river or other outlet, or human waste that has already been released and that you wish to recapture. And which pollutants? It is a broad question and you need to narrow it down. Still, you already received a reasonable answer.

Comment: OH radicals are not exactly complex, but they destroy anything that floats near the surface over time.

Answer (score 3):

Chemical surfactants or dispersants are useful for cleaning up oil spills. They break up the oil slick and allow the oil to become dispersed in the water, so that naturally occurring bacteria can break down and oxidize the hydrocarbons in the oil. Dispersants are typically designed to be water-soluble at one end and oily at the other end--basically soaps or detergents. See http://masgc.org/oilscience/oil-spill-science-dispersant-bkgrnd.pdf for more details.